# Navigating to 2 different pages based on the role of entered user using Firebase and Flutter, role is stored in Cloud Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Based on the email and pass entered I want to show different screen for normal user and admin, this is the code that I tried but it fails to meet the requirement. The role of the user is stored in Cloud Firestore in users collection. The problem arises due to the need to await for checking in the database. I use StreamBuilder.authStateChange for checking whether logged in/off.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            User user = snapshot.data;
            DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(user.uid);
            docRef.get().then((doc) {
              if (doc.exists) {
                if (doc['role'] == 'admin') {
                  return AdminHomeScreen();
                } else {
                  return UserHome();
                }
              } else {
                return AuthScreen();
              }
            });
          } else {
            return AuthScreen();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future: getUserRole(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data == 'admin') {
                return AdminHome();
              } else {
                return UserHome();
              }
            } else {
              return LoginPage();
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> getUserRole() async {
    User user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    DocumentReference docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid);
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await docRef.get();
    return doc['role'];
  }
}
```

Future Builder would be a solution, I tried but it logged out it doesn't show any screen when trying to login, remains in the Auth Screen, I think I am missing something.